# JavaFx layout: disappearing/unorganized panes

Tags: java, javafx

I have a background pane that is meant for drawing objects that is not displaying when used in conjunction with a BorderPane, VBox, and a HBox. Furthermore, my BorderPane is not positioning the layout properly (left, bottom, right).
I have tried using multiple different panes and adding the VBox and HBox to them, however I encounter similar errors where the layout is not as expected and the main drawing pane (canvas) disappears.

```
BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
button1 = new Button("Undo");
button2 = new Button("Erase");
HBox hb = new HBox(10);
hb.getChildren().addAll(button1, button2);

TilePane tp = new TilePane();
vb = new VBox();
vb.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
vb.setSpacing(25);
vb.setStyle("-fx-padding: 10;" + 
        "-fx-border-style: solid inside;" + 
        "-fx-border-width: 2;" +
        "-fx-border-insets: 5;" + 
        "-fx-border-radius: 5;" + 
        "-fx-border-color: black;");

colorCombo = new ComboBox<String>();
colorCombo.getItems().addAll("Black","Blue","Green","Red","Yellow","Orange","Pink");
colorCombo.setValue("Black");
colorCombo.setMinWidth(100);

ToggleGroup group1 = new ToggleGroup();

rbutton1 = new RadioButton("Rectangle");
rbutton1.setToggleGroup(group1);
rbutton1.setMinWidth(80);
rbutton1.setSelected(true);
rbutton2 = new RadioButton("Circle");
rbutton2.setToggleGroup(group1);
rbutton2.setMinWidth(80);

canvas = new Pane();
canvas.setStyle("-fx-background-color: beige;");

vb.getChildren().addAll(colorCombo, rbutton1, rbutton2);
tp.getChildren().add(vb);
bp.setLeft(tp);
bp.setBottom(hb);
bp.setRight(canvas);
this.getChildren().addAll(bp);
```

The TilePane and BorderPane was my latest experiment. I used `bp.setRight(canvas);` to see if I could even get the canvas to show at all even though I want the canvas to be the entire background and not just to the right. The canvas does not show.

Comment: `canvas` has no children and no explicit preferred size, so its size is 0×0 pixels.  If you want the canvas in the center of your window and not the right side, why not call `bp.setCenter` instead of setRight?

Answer (score 1):

I created three separate GridPanes and added the vbox, hbox, and canvas (after setting the minimum height and width) to the gridpanes and then added the gridpanes to a BorderPane. This fixed up the layout for my program.

Answer (score 0):

From [BorderPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html):

> The top and bottom children will be resized to their preferred heights
>   and extend the width of the border pane. **The left and right children
>   will be resized to their preferred widths** and extend the length
>   between the top and bottom nodes. And the center node will be resized
>   to fill the available space in the middle.

For any kind of pane that has no children, its preferred width is 0. You need to explicitly set a width.

One side note: `Pane` would still have preferred width of 0 even if it has children, because `Pane` does not layout its children to determine its own size.

Comment: I've tried setPrefSize() and setMinWidth(). The canvas is still now showing